# Handling connection problems HttpsURLConnection

Tags: java, android, http, rest, https

I have a simple client - server app that downloads files thru a REST API. As I use basic http auth the files are sent via ssl.

```
//my download loop
HttpsURLConnection conn;
//some handling of response codes and content-length
InputStream s = conn.getInputStream();
while (true) {
        i = br.read(buffer); //if server shuts down, I stall here
        if (i == -1)
            break;
        downloadedSize += i;
        fis.write(buffer, 0, i);

    }
```

This all works fine and without issues until the code encounters a situation where the server shuts down a file transfer. At that time the code simply stalls and I have a useless thread.

My question is how to detect that a server has been shut down? In Wireshark I see a RST signal sent, but no exceptions are raised. This seems to me to be a fairly common task and
yet I havent found a straightforward answer to it.

Currently Im using a scheduled task, that checks if there was any progres in downloading every
now and then. If it detects a problem then it creates a new workerThread and tells my communication service to use that one.

This is a very ugly solution as threads then can end up orphaned.

I tried using available() to peek if there is any data available, but as this is SSL, it always returns 0.

Comment: The two approaches I've seen are to (a) wrap the `InputStream` in a `BufferedStreamReader` and use the `ready()` method, or (b) go up through `conn` to get the socket and use the `getSoTimeout()` method.  Can't vouch for the effectiveness of either though.

Comment: ready() wont work, if returns false when using SSL, but I used the timeout solution. Turns out I have been setting the timeout at the wrong time, after actually opening the connection. conn.setReadTimeout(int milis); did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out Ive been calling conn.setReadTimeout(5000); at the wrong place

```
conn = getConnection(address);
    conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

This will cause the read() to fail correctly.